# ayuda con java ee y mysql

Tags: mysql, jsf, java-ee

Quiero utilizar prime face para subir un archivo a servidor y que su ruta se guarde en una base de datos, el registro de la base de datos contiene varios atributos entre ellos la ruta.

Puedo hacer el insert del objeto en la BD, y subir el archivo al servidor, pero por separado cuando intento subirlos juntos no se guarda la ruta en la base de datos (queda campo vació

este es mi codigo:

entity:

```
package sgd.domain;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
* @author David
*/
@Entity 
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByIddoc", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.iddoc = :iddoc"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByNoDoc", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.noDoc = :noDoc"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByFechaDocumento", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.fechaDocumento = :fechaDocumento"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByAntecedente", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.antecedente = :antecedente"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByAsunto", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.asunto = :asunto"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByOrigen", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.origen = :origen"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByDestino", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.destino = :destino"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByEstado", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.estado = :estado"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByRuta", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.ruta = :ruta"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Documentos.findByArea", query = "SELECT d FROM Documentos d WHERE d.area = :area")})
public class Documentos implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
private Integer iddoc;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
private String noDoc;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date fechaDocumento;
private Integer antecedente;
@Size(max = 200)
private String asunto;
@Size(max = 70)
private String origen;
@Size(max = 70)
private String destino;
@Size(max = 45)
private String estado;
@Size(max = 200)
private String ruta;
@Size(max = 45)
private String area;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentos")
private Collection<Anexos> anexosCollection;

public Documentos() {
}

public Documentos(Integer iddoc) {
    this.iddoc = iddoc;
}

public Documentos(String noDoc, Date fechaDocumento, Integer antecedente, String asunto, String origen, String destino, String estado, String ruta, String area) {
    this.noDoc = noDoc;
    this.fechaDocumento = fechaDocumento;
    this.antecedente = antecedente;
    this.asunto = asunto;
    this.origen = origen;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.ruta = ruta;
    this.area = area;
}

public Documentos(Integer iddoc, String noDoc, Date fechaDocumento, Integer antecedente, String asunto, String origen, String destino, String estado, String ruta, String area) {
    this.iddoc = iddoc;
    this.noDoc = noDoc;
    this.fechaDocumento = fechaDocumento;
    this.antecedente = antecedente;
    this.asunto = asunto;
    this.origen = origen;
    this.destino = destino;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.ruta = ruta;
    this.area = area;
}


public Integer getIddoc() {
    return iddoc;
}

public void setIddoc(Integer iddoc) {
    this.iddoc = iddoc;
}

public String getNoDoc() {
    return noDoc;
}

public void setNoDoc(String noDoc) {
    this.noDoc = noDoc;
}

public Date getFechaDocumento() {

    return fechaDocumento;
}

public void setFechaDocumento(Date fechaDocumento) {
    this.fechaDocumento = fechaDocumento;
}

public Integer getAntecedente() {
    return antecedente;
}

public void setAntecedente(Integer antecedente) {
    this.antecedente = antecedente;
}

public String getAsunto() {
    return asunto;
}

public void setAsunto(String asunto) {
    this.asunto = asunto;
}

public String getOrigen() {
    return origen;
}

public void setOrigen(String origen) {
    this.origen = origen;
}

public String getDestino() {
    return destino;
}

public void setDestino(String destino) {
    this.destino = destino;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public String getRuta() {
    return ruta;
}

public void setRuta(String ruta) {
    this.ruta = ruta;
}

public String getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(String area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public Collection<Anexos> getAnexosCollection() {
    return anexosCollection;
}

public void setAnexosCollection(Collection<Anexos> anexosCollection) {
    this.anexosCollection = anexosCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (iddoc != null ? iddoc.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Documentos)) {
        return false;
    }
    Documentos other = (Documentos) object;
    if ((this.iddoc == null && other.iddoc != null) || (this.iddoc != null && !this.iddoc.equals(other.iddoc))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Documentos{" + "iddoc=" + iddoc + ", noDoc=" + noDoc + ", fechaDocumento=" + fechaDocumento + ", antecedente=" + antecedente + ", asunto=" + asunto + ", origen=" + origen + ", destino=" + destino + ", estado=" + estado + ", ruta=" + ruta + ", area=" + area + '}';
}


}
```

ManageBeans

Las clases de interface y DAO no las incluyo, pero se hace una llamada a la base de datos a traves de la persistencia y el servidor de aplicacion es quien maneja la coneccion

```
package sgd.web;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import domain.Documentos;
import sgd.servicio.DocumentosService;
import sgd.utilidades.Constantes;
import static sgd.utilidades.UtilPath.getPath;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

@Named("nuevoRegistro")
@RequestScoped
public class CargarRegistroBD {

//loger para anotar por consola
Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();
//variables injectadas
@Inject
private DocumentosService docuementosService;
private Documentos documentoSeleccionado;


// constructor del Beans
public CargarRegistroBD() {
    log.debug("Iniciando el objeto DocuemtnoBean");
}

//iniciamos las variables
@PostConstruct
public void inicializar() {
    //Inciamos las variables
    this.documentoSeleccionado = new Documentos();

}
// getters and setter  

public Documentos getDocumentoSeleccionado() {
    return documentoSeleccionado;
}

public void setDocumentoSeleccionado(Documentos documentoSeleccionado) {
    this.documentoSeleccionado = documentoSeleccionado;
}
//metodo para agregar un registro a la BD
public void agregarRegistro() {
    this.documentoSeleccionado.setAntecedente(2);
    this.documentoSeleccionado.setEstado("Recibido");
    this.documentoSeleccionado.setRuta(ruta);

    log.debug(documentoSeleccionado.getRuta());
    //se agrega a la base de datos
    this.docuementosService.agregarDocumento(documentoSeleccionado);
    this.documentoSeleccionado = null;
}


private String destino;
private String ruta;
private UploadedFile file;

public String getRuta() {
    return ruta;
}

public void setRuta(String ruta) {
    this.ruta = ruta;
}



public String getDestino() {
    return destino;
}

public void setDestino(String destino) {
    this.destino = destino;
}

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

 public void upload() {
    if (file != null) {
        try {
            destino = Constantes.URL;
            File folder = new File(getPath() + destino);

            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
            copyFile(getFile().getFileName(), getFile().getInputstream());
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Successful", ruta);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);

            this.ruta = "C:\\SistemaSGD\\target\\SistemaSGD-1.0\\resources\\docs"+Constantes.SEPARADORDOBLE+file.getFileName();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error" + e);

        }


    }

}

public void copyFile(String filename, InputStream in) {
    try {
        destino = destino + Constantes.SEPARADOR + filename;
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(getPath() + destino));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Vista

en la vista, primero subo el archivo al servidor y guardo la ruta en String que invoco despues para agregarlo al objeto que persistire en la base de datos, pero al hacer el insert el campo ruta queda vacio.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>prueba</title>
</h:head>
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">   

    <p:fileUpload value="#{nuevoRegistro.file}" mode="simple" skinSimple="true"/>
<br />
<p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" action="#{nuevoRegistro.upload}" disabled="false" />
<h:outputText id="ruta" value="#{nuevoRegistro.ruta}"/>
</h:form>
<h:body>


    <p:growl id="NuevoRegistro" showDetail="true" />

    <h:form id="FormNuevoRegstro" enctype="multipart/from-data" >
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="Numero doc"/>
            <h:inputText value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.noDoc}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="fecha de Documento" />
            <p:calendar id="fechaDocumento" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.fechaDocumento}"   showOn="button" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="asunto"  />
            <h:inputText value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.asunto}" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <h:outputText value="origen" />
            <h:inputText value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.origen}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div>

            <h:outputText value="Destino" />
            <h:inputText value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.destino}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div>            
            <h:outputText value="area" />
            <h:inputText value="#{nuevoRegistro.documentoSeleccionado.area}" required="true"/>

        </div>

        <div>

            <p:commandButton value="Enviar" ajax="false" action="#{nuevoRegistro.agregarRegistro}" disabled="false" />
        </div>



    </h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="regresar" action="index" />


 </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hasta el momento, creo que no funciona porque tengo que poner en 2 formularios la  informacion, en uno pongo la carga del archivo, y en otro la carga de la base de datos, y como su alcance es request, cuando subo el archivo se pierde el valor de la ruta, asi que agregue una variable donde guardar la ruta, y luego en el formulario de la base de datos, le insterto el valor de la variable en el campo de ruta